# Changing the color of Donorbox donation widget on Squarespace based on the page?

Tags: squarespace, donations

I have a few different pages on my nonprofit website, each in a different color (don't ask why, long answer). I'm using [Donorbox](http://donorbox.org) to accept donations. I'm trying to change the form color based on the page. Here is the code I'm embedding

I followed the instructions here - [How To Embed Donorbox recurring form on Squarespace](https://donorbox.org/nonprofit-blog/squarespace-embedding/)

I've tried adding a css property for color for each Iframe, but that's not working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

With [Donorbox](https://donorbox.org) you can now change your donation form's color without coding css. It is a relatively new feature that they launched.

Here is a guide on how customize your recurring donation form in different color using the Donorbox form editor https://donorbox.org/nonprofit-blog/custom-donation-form-colors/

Using this technique you can embed different [recurring donation forms](https://donorbox.org/nonprofit-blog/wordpress-embedding/) on different pages of your website.

Hope this helps.